# Show ModelState errors in the View only on form POST

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a multi-step registration form:

Page 1 (email) -> Page 2 (name) -> Page 3 (Success)

On my page 1 the email field can be pre-populated via the query string.

The problem is on Page 2 I can not display the validation errors if the name field is empty and submitted.

If I apply the required attribute to the name fields to the page 2 model, then the page 1 -> page 2 call will always fail. So i took out the required attribute and created a duplicate view model for page 3, same as page 2 but with the required attributes on the name. Now page 3 can detect if the name is empty and the model is invalid, so at this point i redirect back to page 2, but the View on page 2 will not show the validation errors around the name fields.

What can I do ?

ViewModel code:

```
public Class StepOneViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Email{ get; set; }
}


public Class StepTwoViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Email{ get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public Class StepTwoViewModelPOST
{
    [Required]
    public string Email{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller code:

```
        public ActionResult Step1(string email)
        {
           return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Step1(StepOneViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return View();
            else
                return RedirectToAction("Step2", viewModel);
        }

        public ActionResult Step2(StepTwoViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return RedirectToAction("Step1", viewModel);
            else
            {
                return View(viewModel);
            }
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Step2(StepTwoViewModelPOST viewModel)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return RedirectToAction("Step1", viewModel);
            else
            {
                return Content("Success");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why not post page2/Index to page2/Step2?  You can check the model state as the values are posted, and if there are any problems return View("Index", ViewModel).  If there are no errors, then redirect to Page3,

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are proposing with page2/index to page2/step2

Comment: @newbie: I reformatted the code in your question, cause if was not very clear and so you could easily miss some part of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured this out... On the POST handler for Step2, if the ModeState is not valid, I just need to map StepTwoViewModelPOST  => StepTwoViewModel  and then simply return View with the model.

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Step2(StepTwoViewModelPOST viewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
             StepTwoViewModel model = new StepTwoViewModel { 
                  Email = viewModel.Email,
                  FirstName = viewModel.FirstName,
                  LastName = viewModel.LastName
              };
            return View(model);
        }
        else
        {
            return Content("Success");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

### Here you have "workflow" issues. Do it PRG!

What is PRG? [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). So try do have the following forms workflow:

1. GET step1
2. POST step1 (check `ModelState.IsValid` if it is not return `View`)
3. Redirect to step 2
4. GET step2
   5 ...

Make sense?

Of course the data should be saved between the steps. You can do it on client side (cookie, [sesvars](http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html), local storage, ...) or on server side (session, some persistence). However I would recommend that you use just ASP.NET session.

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm doing, PRG! Please see the code I posted in the question.

Comment: You didn't offer any solution to my specific problem. Would love to explore any alternate solutions apart from the one I've posted. Hate to have duplicate ViewModels for GET and POST.

Comment: Well, I guess the "Point 2" give the solution as it seems (to check the model state). However, if you want to have only one ViewModel, well have it! This would mean that you do not use the "whole" view model in each step but you will have it everything in one place, so try to have it like this. The only question remains where to store the step data. Luckily, I also put some solutions to this in my answer.